# Метод Equals C#

Tags: c#, equals

Разбираюсь в тонкостях языка, не понимаю почему возвращает false, если equals сравнивает именно значения в памяте, а не ссылки. Есть хорошая статья, где все понятно объясняется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и даже так false

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `equals сравнивает именно значения в памяте, а не ссылки` - неверное утверждение. 1) код надо вставлять текстом 2) потому что ссылочные типы сравниваются по ссылке, если Equals не переопределён, то есть в данном случае поведение Equals идентично ReferenceEquals 4) для сравнения по содержимому массивов есть SequenceEqual `a.SequenceEqual(b)`, ну либо можете написать код сравнения массивов сами с циклом. У `string` например Equals переопределен, поэтому он работает по содержимому, хотя строка - тоже ссылочный тип.

Comment: спасибо, очень помог